# How to route requests to MVC controllers to an application tier

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, security, architecture

My team is reviewing security on a 2-tier ASP MVC application and has decided to introduce an service tier to prevent the website connecting directly to the database. I'm looking for ways to avoid a large rewrite of the application.

Is there a framework to route all controller calls to a service? Microsoft have a similar framework to introduce an intermediary for WCF services. Is there anything similar for MVC?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/routing-service

Comment: An MVC application is not a 2-tier app.  The browser is one tier.  The Controllers are one tier, and the database is one tier.  What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I'm trying to introduce another physical tier so that if the web server is compromised, an attacker will only be able to reach an application server rather than the database server.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to introduce another physical tier so that if the web server is compromised. . .

Cool.  You can solve that problem without changing the applciation at all using a Reverse Proxy.  Like

[IIS Application Request Routing](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing)

Or, for internet-facing or cloud applications [Azure Web Application Gateway / Web Application Firewall](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-gateway/)